# DLQ, bounded retry, and EOS when producing to multiple topics using Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka, spring-cloud-function

I am trying to write a transform function which will consume an input from one topic and produce two outputs to topics Left and Right. Moreover I need this to take place in a transaction so that if the application fails to produce a message to Right, it will roll back its attempt to Left. Furthermore, Kafka should re-attempt delivery to the transform's consumer in the event of failure so that the application has multiple chances to recover from transient errors. However, if the error is chronic, I need the application to give up after some number (let's say 3) attempts, at which point the message should be delivered to a DLQ.

I understand how to achieve bounded retry, DLQ, and transactions using the imperative model. That is, I can use `Function<IN, OUT>` and get 90% of the way to a solution. However, to the best of my understanding, `Function<IN, Tuple2<OUT1, OUT2>>` is not a supported signature at the moment, and I have to use the reactive programming model to deliver to multiple topics. Furthermore, automatic DLQ is not, as I understand it, part of the framework for reactive consumers. It also does not look like transactions are managed the same way, and consumer offset commits appear to be automatic instead of conditional on the success or failure of the stream processing.

Can someone advise how I can write a consumer which:

- transforms an input into two outputs,
- publishes those outputs to two topics atomically (rolling back if anything goes wrong),
- re-tries to ingest, transform, and publish message up to a maximum of 3 times in the presence of any failure,
- and if all re-tries are exhausted, enqueues the message to a DLQ so that the application is not blocked?

This *does not* need to be reactive to answer my question.

The following is what I have tried so far, adapted from my initial single-output imperative function that met the other requirements. It is intended to consume integers one at a time from the input topic, create an audit_log database record within a transaction (if that fails, roll everything back and try again), transform the number to two json payloads labeled "left" or "right," then publish the json to outputs 0 and 1 from the signature. I was trying to use output 3 for the DLQ, since errors from a reactive stream are not automatically DLQ'd as with the imperative model. This is exploratory code just to learn the ropes, so there are random chances to throw RTEs in order to exercise failure scenarios.

In the presence of an exception, the current message is lost without retry. If the application publishes one of two messages and the latter is interrupted by an exception, the former is nonetheless committed (no transaction rollback seems to take place). Finally, because all errors are dropped, they never reach my code to try to deliver them to a DLQ.

```java
@Bean
@Transactional
public Function<Flux<Message<Integer>>, Tuple3<Flux<String>, Flux<String>, Flux<Object>>>
    numberToJson(AuditLogRepository repository) {
  var random = new Random();

  // I tried to create two sinks, one for each output topic. This works fine.
  var left = Sinks.many().unicast().<Integer>onBackpressureBuffer();
  var right = Sinks.many().unicast().<Integer>onBackpressureBuffer();

  // I tried to use this sink for the DLQ destination. I was hoping to manually shuffle UE's to the DLQ.
  var dlq = Sinks.many().unicast().onBackpressureBuffer();

  return flux -> {
    // Do a database operation (in a transaction).
    var persistent =
        flux.map(
                message -> {
                  var n = message.getPayload();
                  repository.createIfNotExists("Transformed n=" + n);
                  if (random.nextDouble() < 0.3) {
                    LOGGER.error("Transformer failure on n=" + n);
                    throw new RuntimeException("Transformer failure on n=" + n);
                  }
                  return message;
                })
            .doOnNext(
                message -> {
                  var n = message.getPayload();
                  left.tryEmitNext(n).orThrow();

                  // If only one side fails to publish, we want the txn to roll back.
                  if (random.nextDouble() < 0.1) {
                    LOGGER.error("Failed to publish right-side JSON: n=" + n);
                    throw new RuntimeException("Failed to publish right-side JSON: n=" + n);
                  }
                  right.tryEmitNext(n).orThrow();
                })
            .retry(3) // Make 3 attempts overall to process and publish. If that fails, continue
                      // to the DLQ.
            .onErrorContinue(
                (error, message) -> {
                  dlq.tryEmitNext(message).orThrowWithCause(error);
                })
            .retry() // If DLQ fails and this flux crashes, always restart it. The failed message
                     // will be redelivered.
            .publish()
            .autoConnect(3);

    // Split the "persistent" flux into three, which map to separate kafka topics and DLQ.
    return Tuples.of(
        left.asFlux()
            .doOnSubscribe(_sub -> persistent.subscribe())
            .map(n -> toJson(n, "left"))
            .retry(),
        right
            .asFlux()
            .doOnSubscribe(_sub -> persistent.subscribe())
            .map(n -> toJson(n, "right"))
            .retry(),
        dlq.asFlux().doOnSubscribe(_sub -> persistent.subscribe()).retry());
  };
}
```

Finally, here are the relevant bits of my `application.yml`. I have some configuration left over from the imperative attempt, such as the Kafka DLQ setup. I've omitted the publishers and consumers which are earlier or later in the stream, because I know those are working fine.

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          transaction:
            transaction-id-prefix: 'tx-'
            producer:
              configuration:
                retries: 3
                acks: all
        bindings:
          numberToJson-in-0:
            consumer:
              enableDlq: true
          numberToJson-out-0:
            producer:
              topic.properties:
                retention.bytes: 10000
      bindings:
        numberToJson-in-0:
          destination: tx-number
          group: numberToJson
          consumer:
            # Not sure how this interacts with the flux retries, if at all.
            maxAttempts: 2
            properties:
              isolation.level: read_committed
        numberToJson-out-0:
          destination: tx-json-left
          producer:
            partitionCount: 3
        numberToJson-out-1:
          destination: tx-json-right
        numberToJson-out-2:
          # Manually wiring the function's 3rd output to a DLQ.
          destination: error.tx-number.numberToJson
    function:
      definition: numberToJson
```

[EDIT]
This is the imperative consumer I had tried to equip with a Tuple2 signature, which otherwise works:

```java
@Bean
@Transactional
public Function<Integer, Tuple2<String, String>> numberToJson(
    AuditLogRepository repository) {
  var random = new Random();

  return n -> {
    LOGGER.info("Transforming n=" + n);
    var left = "{ \"n\": \"" + n + "\", \"side\": \"left\" }";
    var right = "{ \"n\": \"" + n + "\", \"side\": \"right\" }";

    repository.createIfNotExists("Transformed n=" + n);

    if (random.nextDouble() < 0.3) {
      LOGGER.error("Transformer failure on n=" + n);
      throw new RuntimeException("Transformer failure on n=" + n);
    }

    return Tuples.of(left, right);
  };
}
```

But, this is met with the following exception at runtime:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'functionInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/stream/function/FunctionConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: At the moment only Tuple-based function are supporting multiple arguments
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `StreamBridge` and add a configured `AfterRollbackProcessor`.

The following example includes consumers on `left`, `right`, and `input.DLT`.

```java
@SpringBootApplication(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class So68928091Application {

    @Autowired
    StreamBridge bridge;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So68928091Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    Consumer<String> input() {
        return str -> {
            System.out.println(str);
            this.bridge.send("left", str.toUpperCase());
            this.bridge.send("right", str.toLowerCase());
            if (str.equals("Fail")) {
                throw new RuntimeException("test");
            }
        };
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    @Bean
    ListenerContainerCustomizer<AbstractMessageListenerContainer<?, ?>> customizer(BinderFactory binders) {
        return (container, dest, group) -> {
            ProducerFactory<byte[], byte[]> pf = ((KafkaMessageChannelBinder) binders.getBinder(null,
                    MessageChannel.class)).getTransactionalProducerFactory();
            KafkaTemplate<byte[], byte[]> template = new KafkaTemplate<>(pf);
            DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor rollbackProcessor = rollbackProcessor(template);
            container.setAfterRollbackProcessor(rollbackProcessor);
        };
    }

    DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor rollbackProcessor(KafkaTemplate<byte[], byte[]> template) {
        return new DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor<>(
                new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(template), new FixedBackOff(2000L, 2L), template, true);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("input.DLT").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topicLeft() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("left").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topicRight() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("right").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "left", topics = "left")
    public void listenLeft(String in) {
        System.out.println("left:" + in);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "right", topics = "right")
    public void listenRight(String in) {
        System.out.println("right:" + in);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "dlt", topics = "input.DLT")
    public void listenDlt(String in) {
        System.out.println("dlt:" + in);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<byte[], byte[]> template) {
        return args -> {
            System.in.read();
            template.send("input", "Fail".getBytes());
            template.send("input", "Good".getBytes());
        };
    }

}
```

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.transaction.transaction-id-prefix: tx-
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.required-acks=all
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input-in-0.group=foo
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input-in-0.destination=input
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.left.destination=left
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.right.destination=right

#For @KafkaListeners

spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.isolation-level=read-committed
```

```
Fail
...
Fail
...
Fail
...
Good
dlt:Fail
right:good
left:GOOD
```

Remove all DLT settings in the binding, and set `maxAttempts` to 1 to disable retries there.

Comment: Correction; the rollback processor and dead letter publisher need a transactional `KafkaTemplate` using the binder's producer factory.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm trying to get this working locally. I had my kafka instance configured via s.c.s.kafka.binder.brokers and s.c.s.kafka.binder.configuration (e.g. for SASL). It looks like to use the Kafka Listeners, I have to replicate that over to s.kafka.bootstrap-servers and s.k.properties; is it expected to have the same config in two places?

Comment: Well, the binder will use the `spring.kafka.*` properties first; then apply the binder properties as overrides, so you can just move them there rather than copying them. Or you can add bindings to consume from those topics instead of `@KafkaListener`s. I only added those consumers so we can see that it works as expected.

Comment: That helps, thank you. I'm also having trouble getting database transactions working again using this approach. Previously I only had to add a `@Transactional` annotation, as in the Q, but that doesn't seem to work now. If I create a DataSourceTransactionManager bean and use `@Transactional("my-tx-bean")` [EDIT: or just `@Transactionl`, apparently!], though, it looks like it works. I _think_ that's what [these docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#container-transaction-manager) say? Could you confirm?

Comment: I was mistaken, it's not actually working (I was just hiding the error logs and missed the fact that nothing was going to the DB.) I'll open a separate Q. Thanks again Gary, you've been a huge help.

Comment: What about the code smells which SONAR raises due to generic wildcard types and lack of parameterized type for generic usage ?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean; ask a new question with more specifics.